# Notice: Array to string conversion error

Tags: magento2, conversion

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/sailorplastic/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Html/Select.php on line 243
```

I get above error in Admin log magento2 when i am trying to see mailchimp store configuration setting. I have also done data migration.

How can i debug this error?

Comment: This error is showing variable data is in array type not a string so according to it you have to change echo to print_r or else if you putting variable in log then you have set variable in print_r($var,true);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is showing `variable` data is in array type not a string so according to it you have to change `echo` to `print_r` or else if you putting variable in `log` file then you have to put variable in `print_r($var,true)`;

That's all.