# Notice: Array to string conversion in Escaper.php on line 261 after Upgrade from 2.3.5 to 2.4.0

Tags: magento2, magento-upgrade

System: PHP 7.3, MySql 5.7, Magento 2.4

After Upgrade

```
Exception: Notice: Array to string conversion in Escaper.php on line 261
```

This effect is only while displaying a Product grid with Image other works correctly. Same Effect in Widget new Product.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

This error is showing variable data is in array type, not a string so according to it you have to change echo to print_r`or else if you putting the variable in log file then you have to put the`variable in print_r($var, true);

[reference link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/253622/notice-array-to-string-conversion-error)

also, check this link for [Magento 2.4.0 Requirement](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html).

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the error is originating from the call to getImage:

getImage($_item, $image)->toHtml() ?>

Further investigation leads to a theme override of vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/image_with_borders.phtml ‎which was heavily modified in 2.4.0. Disabling this override fixes the problem‎.